# ext js Form.Submit always returns failure

Tags: c#, json, extjs

Good Morning All,

I am trying a very basic form.submit and for some reason it ALWAYS comes back as failure.
Also using a local webservice in .NET.

I must be missing something very basic... or maybe something with the way the data is coming back.

I have attached few pictures to show how I am attempting:

image1 - form.submit

[image]

image2 - service.cs

[image]

image3 - how I am returning result from .NET webservice locally
[image]

Apologies for the images... for some reason cutting and pasting code is not working.

Thank you!
Stephen

here is a picture of debugger in webservice
first row is var variable
second row (x2) is converted to json using JsonConvert.SerializeObject
[image]

lastly is a pictures of debugger from browser upon return
[image]

I also have been trying to understand CORS... so I added the following to my web.config which doesn't help

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

here is firefox debugger
[image]

I adjusted my web.config to allow options and still get error
STATUS CODE 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT" />
        <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />-->
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

OKAY... I made some changes... I removed those lines from my web.config and added a Global.asax.cs page with the following:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Now it seems to go through successfully, but still hits failure.  Am I on to something here?  Is it my json format?

result

[image: newresult]

[image: json]

[image: network]

Comment: strange, everything seems correct. can you make sure response is {success:true} ? what version of extjs are yo using?

Comment: I added debugger views to from both my webserver and the browser upon return to show the results. also I believe I am in version6 but not sure how to check

Comment: in console check Ext.getVersion()

Comment: 6.01.250, I added some headers to my web.config shown above which did not help.

Comment: look at request method. it says `OPTIONS`. which is not allowed in your server. allow it and after `OPTIONS` method will be sent your `GET` method described in form submit.

Comment: I adjusted my web.config to allow options and still get an error. do I need to have some method in my service called OPTIONS?

Comment: As http GET and POST where is also http method OPTIONS [http method OPTIONS](http://zacstewart.com/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html)

Comment: sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean, can you explain?

Comment: open link in previous comment and read it. I cannot explain it.

Comment: okay I removed section from myweb.config and handles OPTIONS in my global page.  still error but now I get a GREEN indicator.  maybe something with format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response has backslashes, which is not valid JSON. It has to be `{"success":true}` without backslashes.

This should be due to double serialization. Where you debugged it, it's OK. But you should be serializing it one more time somewhere else. Make sure you avoid double serialization.

Comment: its version 6.0250. I tried returning the var json.ToString() which is "{success = True}" but that doesn't seem right either.  If I change my browser to Chrome I get response for preflight has invalid http status code 405

Comment: finally got it. thanks for your help walking me through it!  it was a combination of returning a bad format of json, it should have returning the object directly, not a string version.  then also adding a global.asax file and editing httpcontext headers in application_beginrequest